# Display result of POST or GET to external site within jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to POST to an external website, and display the results in a jQuery UI Dialog on my site. Is that possible? I've tried a bunch of permutations, for example (with GET):

```
$("#view").click(function() {
var url = this.href;
var dialog_pop = $('<div></div>');
dialog_pop.load(url).dialog();
return false; });
```

This seems to work if the target URL is within my domain, but doesn't work if it's an external site. Also, I haven't gotten POST to work yet either.

What can I try to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a normal XmlHttpRequest, which jQuery AJAX uses.  This restriction is part of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that browsers enforce or security reasons.

What you *can* do is use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) if the other domain supports transferring data in that fashion.  It's basically a specialized way of passing JSON and calling a function that exists on your side.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a POST to your domain like this:

```
$.post(url, data, function(result) {
    $('<div>' + data + '</div>').dialog();
});
```

However, as has already been mentioned, you cannot send a normal AJAX request to a different domain.